# What impacts SAS data set performance more - number of observations or number of variables?

Tags: performance, dataset, sas

After working with different data sets in SAS for a month or two, it seems to me that the more variables a data set has, the more time it takes to run PROCs and other operations on the data set.  Yet if I have for example 5 variables, but 1 million observations, performance is not impacted too much.

While I'm interested in if observations or variables affect performance, I was also wondering if there are other factors I'm missing in looking at SAS performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same size data set (rows*columns) the one with more variables will usually be slower I believe.  I tried creating two data sets with either 1 row and 10000 columns, or 1 column and 10000 rows.  The one with more variables took a lot more memory and time.

```
options fullstimer;
data a;
    retain var1-var10000 1;
run;
data b(drop=i);
    do i=1 to 10000;
    var1=i;
    output;
    end;
run;
```

On the Log

```
31   options fullstimer;
32   data a;
33       retain var1-var10000 1;
34   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.A has 1 observations and 10000 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.23 seconds
      user cpu time       0.20 seconds
      system cpu time     0.03 seconds
      Memory                            5382k
      OS Memory                         14208k
      Timestamp            10/14/2009  2:03:57 PM


35   data b(drop=i);
36       do i=1 to 10000;
37       var1=i;
38       output;
39       end;
40   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.B has 10000 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      user cpu time       0.00 seconds
      system cpu time     0.01 seconds
      Memory                            173k
      OS Memory                         12144k
      Timestamp            10/14/2009  2:03:57 PM
```

You should also check out [BUFNO=](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/62618/HTML/default/a000131098.htm#a000131101) and [BUFSIZE=](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/62618/HTML/default/a000131102.htm).  If you have to access a data set many times, you might consider using [SASFILE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/62618/HTML/default/a001500739.htm) as well to store the entire data set in memory.

Comment: SASFILE sounds useful, but my data set is too large for the machine I'm on (~1.8gb, and I get constant not-enough-memory errors when I try to SASFILE it).  Thanks for doing those quick tests!

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite elucidate (and am making an educated guess), but I imagine it has something to do with a combination of factors, including that a whole record is read into the PDV, which means more data sits in memory with many variables.

It might be worth doing some measurements with compressed datasets, because I/O is often the bottleneck.

SAS dataset option:

```
data foo(compress=yes);
...
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try out compression today.  The HD on the machine I'm running on is constantly thrashing when running through the hundreds of PROC REPORT statements I'm currently using, so I think it is definitely I/O and compress might help!

Comment: Compressions is helping quite a bit with my large data set.  Thanks!

Comment: In addition to single data sets, you can also set compression as a global option or as a library option for different levels of granularity.